# How to match up 2 columns with 2 other columns

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

In column A I have product id's and column B has the number of times the product in column A was quoted.

In column C I have the same product id's (but in different order) and column D has the number of times the product in column C was actually sold.

I want to match them up to add a final column in order to divide sales/quoted in order to get a value of efficiency in sales.

I believe it's an index/match/match but I'm not sure how to set it up.

Please help[image: 4 columns]

Comment: Sidenote: You have many open question without accepted answer. Would be appreciated if you revisit them and see which of these threads can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=B3/vlookup(A3,C:D,2,false)
```

In words: take the value in B3 and divide it by the value from column D where column C has the same text as A3.

Comment: I thought it worked but it doesnt.  I looked wrong the first time but it only worked for the items that were lined up properly.

Comment: How does "it doesn't work" manifest? What does the formula return? Wrong values or errors?

Comment: nevermind, i wrote the formula wrong.  GOT IT!  Thanks so much